# Pipes in C LINUX

Tags: pipe

Hi i need to create a program of C language to create three child processes. Each child process sends two messages through pipe. The parent process waits in a loop using a select ( ) system call to check the read ends of the pipes and standard input device as well. The messages sent by the child processes and the character input by the user should be displayed by the parent process in the order they arrived.

i know how to work with 2 pipes but don't know about this one please help me..

i did this in main function

```
 if (pipe(pipe1) == -1) 
        {
                perror("pipe1 error");
                return 0;
        }
        if (pipe(pipe2) == -1) 
        {
                perror("pipe2 error");
                return 0;
        }

        if (pipe(pipe3) == -1) 
        {
                perror("pipe3 error");
                return 0;
        }
                    //fork for child and parent.(server/client).
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) 
        {
                    //parent as client. 
                close(pipe1[0]);    //close read - 0 for read
                close(pipe2[1]);    //close write - 1 for write.
                server(pipe2[0], pipe1[1]);

        }
        else 
        {
                    //child as server.
            close(pipe1[1]);      
                close(pipe2[0]);     
                client(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]);
                wait(NULL);     //wait for child process to finish


                return 0;
        }
```

but these are 2 pipes not 3 i need to make it..

Comment: Repeat the same code 2 more times.

Comment: how :/ ? and sir please read the question ... how can i do that?

Comment: You do them the exact same way. Just keep repeating the parent code. Have you even tried? You'll never learn to be a programmer if you just get people to do it for you. You have to program to be a programmer.

Comment: This is obviously homework, and it would be cheating for us to do it for you.

Comment: i thought this web was to help .. obviously we program by ourselves but sometimes we stuck..

Comment: Yes, we're here to help, not do it for you. You make an attempt to solve it, and if it doesn't work you post what you tried, and we show you where you went wrong.